# LLVM libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called and unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, llvm, libc++

I am writing a main function that is supposed to call other functions, and , but I am getting this error 
`libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called!`

the way i inject function calls into main function is :

```
Type * returnType = Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext);
    std::vector<Type *> argTypes(0, Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext));

    FunctionType * functionType = FunctionType::get(returnType, argTypes, false);
    Function * function = Function::Create(functionType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", TheModule.get());
    function->getBasicBlockList().clear();
    BasicBlock * BB = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", function);

    Builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);
    for (const auto & call : calls) {
        Builder.CreateCall(call.first, call.second, "call");
    }
    Builder.CreateRet(Builder.getInt32(0));
    verifyFunction(*function);
```

and if i run this for loop, i get mentioned error 
but generated IR seems to be fine, except for some reason it calls "calltmp? instead of "call" do you know how can i fix this ?

```
declare i32 @writeln(i32)

define i32 @a() {
entry:
  ret i32 3
}

ine i32 @__anon_call() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call i32 @a()
  %calltmp1 = call i32 @writeln(i32 %calltmp)
  ret i32 %calltmp1

entry2:                                           ; No predecessors!
  %calltmp3 = call i32 @a()
  %calltmp4 = call i32 @writeln(i32 %calltmp3)
  ret i32 %calltmp4
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %call = call i32 @a()
  %call1 = call i32 @writeln(i32 %calltmp)
  %call2 = call i32 @a()
  %call3 = call i32 @writeln(i32 %calltmp3)
  ret i32 0
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this with "libc++", since I see no standard library bits here.

Comment: @MarshallClow because that is the error i got. And it confuses me quiet a lot as well. I was hoping someone with advanced knowledge will be able to explain why does this happen, I am sure that llvm itself uses libc++ at some point

Comment: `libc++abi` is a support library that handles things like exception unwinding etc for libc++.